# why do some people don't use scikit-learn library instead of writing long python functions?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data-science-model, kaggle

The other day I was exploring Kaggle and I found most of them don't use `scikit-learn` or any other library but instead they write these long python scripts.
For example, why they write a function for train/test split when you can just use the `scikit-learn` library which is hassle free
are there any advantages of not using any library and writing python code directly.

p.s: I'm a Data Science Beginner.

Comment: Can you point us to any specific example of such custom function?

Comment: One possible advantage is to acquire a good understanding of what the function does and how it works. We often see people who know which functions to use for standard tasks, but they don't have a good understanding of what the functions do and thus can make serious mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple reasons to write a custom code instead of using a library.
For example - you can use the `train_test_split` from `sklearn` and that will generate a random split of data for `training` and `validation`. But let's assume you want to have a `specific distribution` of `target` in training and `validation` then you need to write a `custom function` to apply that `specific distribution` while preparing the `training` and `validation`

Comment: By "specific distribution", can you name one such example?

Comment: More details can be found [here](https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/subsampling-1/)